# What does it mean when we say that some function is polynomially bigger/smaller than some other function?

Tags: algorithms, complexity

I was going over this [video lecture on  master theorem from Introduction to Algorithm](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-2-asymptotic-notation-recurrences-substitution-master-method/)  and while explaining case A of the  master theorem professor says that some function `f(n)` is polynomially smaller than some other function at point 53:08 seconds:

[image: formula]

What does it mean for a function to be polynomially smaller than this function?

I am confused here as polynomially is not equivalent to poly-logarithmically. Has the professor used the wrong term here ? It is highly unlikely though since he goes on to say the same term a number of times.

Comment: Can you give the functions in your post?

Comment: @phant0m I already provided the link to that function .

Comment: I think the professor meant that one algorithm scales better then the other. Once things get more complex, the slower algorithm will perform worse and worse then the better one.

Comment: note professor uses wording "polynomially **smaller** / larger" ([screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rxTJj.png)). Searching the web for this wording yields interesting results (eg [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37332/asymptotically-larger-vs-polynomially-larger), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931657/polynomially-larger-confusion))

Comment: Yes, but it's much better if you include all necessary information in your post, not just link to it.

Comment: btw, he mentions that you need `"divine inspirations"` to guess closed forms for these recurrences, but you can also figure it out systematically (30:30) -  at least for the formula that he's working on it's quite simple.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short: a smaller(bigger) exponent of n.

It relates directly to a part of my answer to an earlier question of yours [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/158569/please-explain-the-statement-that-the-function-anb-belongs-to-on2-and-and/158575#158575):

[image: formula], which basically says that n to some power grows faster, if the exponent is bigger, regardless of constant factors.

---

In case 1, function `f(n)` is assumed to be polynomially smaller than this one:
[image]

Don't get scared by the logarithm here, it is *just a number*, because `a` and `b` are constants, so is `log_b(a)`. (Which is why poly-logarithmically does not enter the picture, in that case)

It is then defined to what class of functions `f(n)` must belong to. This is already the answer to your question `"what it means to be polynomially smaller"`:

[image: polynomially smaller formula]

All it means is, that the exponent of `n` must be less than `log_b(a)`: You subtract a positive number (epsilon) from it.

This is another way of looking at it:

[image]

The polynomially bigger one has more factors of n: `epsilon` more. (or less in the case of smaller)

---

At `57:30` he gives an example, where he ends up in case 1: He compares `f(n) = n` with `n^2`. `f(n)` is polynomially smaller because `1 < 2`.

Comment: What is log_b(a) ? What does underscore and () signify ? What is the base here ?

Comment: log_b(a) means log to the base b of a ?Still confused with the underscore .

Comment: @Geek Exactly. The underscore is used to indicate subscript. Does that help?